# Show error if pm library doesn't exist

Tags: perl

**"Interesting" dilemma this one**.

To use a lib in perl, you obviously include "use lib x" command ... but what can you do if "x.pm" doesn't exist, (or more correctly per chance deleted by server admin)

In short, I 'hide' this file in with the .htaccess and other files in the root of my account, ie below the "public_html" folder - to keep it away from prying eyes. So I can set the path in the script such as "use /home/account/x" and all is well.

In the past, I think security measures mean this file sometimes gets removed. So when the script runs, the viewer sees a glorious "500 Error"

I tried:

```
 If (-e 'use /home/account/x'){
 use 'home/account/x';
 ...
 }
 else{
 print "error";
 }
```

But all that does is say it cannot find the use command on the line below "If"

Tried:

```
use 'home/account/x' || die ('cannot find file')
```

But that syntax is wrong. Is there any simple way around this?

Answer (score 5):

This is to do with when the error can be 'noticed'. [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) happens at *compile* time. Thus - you can't do many of the normal program flow things that you'd do. (There are a few exceptions).

But what you can do instead, is [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) which loads things at run time - at a point where you can do the sort of tests you would want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

eval { require "Not_here.pm" };
warn "Couldn't load: $@" if $@;
print "fish";
```

Although, you may also need to `import` the routines you want, after `requiring` the module, because `use` does:

```
 BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

Comment: You can string `eval` `use` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use string `eval` to check if a module exists, if I can run without it.

```
our $have_unac = 0;
BEGIN {
    eval "use Text::Unaccent::PurePerl";
    $have_unac = 1 if (!$@);
}
```

Comment: At present - until advised to the contrary - I have made a "mash" of the two. ideas. I used:  eval(require "x.pm"); if ($@){print error}else{BEGIN{eval "use x"} qfrvjqf 1_!l_I1_1nbjm_obsg1_ldhj-ajm1_lnk_fq ... data to be decoded by library no x}  So if the first require can't find the file, prints an error, but if it is found, the BEGIN within else statement loads the library and decodes the data. It works, but whether it follows the correct convention I don't know.

Comment: This is not advisable. First of all the `BEGIN` block will be run anyway, and before anything else in your script. Second of all trying to require it after it is used might have side-effects. (I have not thought too much about this.) You should use either my version or @Sobrique's